# Json Array having multiple JsonObject Conversion to map based on java8

Tags: json, java-8, org.json

I have multiple apps which returns a JsonArray having multiple JsonObject
like this e.g for app1

```
[ {"Server":"PCF","Port":"9878","Calls":"655"},
{"Server":"AWS","Port":"5672","Calls":"655"},.... ].
```

Fields in all the JsonObject are same.
    I want to create a map based on field Server which contains a list of JsonObject.

```
"PCF":[{"Server":"PCF","Port":"9878","Calls":"655"}, {"Server":"PCF","Port":"562","Calls":"65"}]
```

Conditions:
    1) I want to use java8(I have done on older version).
    2) I am using org.json.

Comment: please share old version code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used the JSON-Java library before but from a little bit of research, seems to suggest that [JsonArray](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html) from org.json implements `java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.Object>` therefore we could do:

```
Map<String, List<JSONObject>> result = 
            StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
                         .map(f -> (JSONObject) f) // assumes every 'f' is a JSONObject otherwise use filter before map
                         .collect(groupingBy(f -> f.getString("Server")));
```

if you don't cast to a `JSONObject` then this would return:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result =
                StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
                             .collect(groupingBy(f -> ((JSONObject)f).getString("Server")));
```

imports:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

Comment: StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)
                             .collect(groupingBy(f -> ((JSONObject)f).getString("Server"))); It works but it is for one jsonaray.As i said earlier i have multiple app how can i put all that mapping into a common map.